# Missing path in Pythonpath for python 2, but it exists for python 3

Tags: python, virtualenv, pythonpath, virtualenvwrapper

I'm using virtualenwrapper for my virtual environments. And when developed a package for pypi it worked fine developing in python3. However when I tried testing it with a python2 environment that I created with virtualenwrapper I can no longer import the modules I want to.

When checking the python path for my python3 environment it contains `/Users/jonathan/projects/myproject` whereas the python2 environment contains no such mention.

Do I need to set the path explicitly when working with a python2 environment somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

For any command that needed the PYTHONPATH for the current directory I made a makefile that had `$(shell export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$(pwd))` before I ran the actual command. That solved my problem.